# Asp.net + JIT?

Tags: asp.net

What is default type of JIT compiler is used in .Net (visual studio)
out of (Pre-JIT,Econo-JIT,Normal-JIT)?

Comment: Did you make up those names? Or did you read about them somewhere? Please provide a link, if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know default JIT is Pre-JIT but [ASP.NET Does Not Support Pre-Just-In-Time (JIT) Compilation Through Native Image Generator](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/331979).

A little bit of background on the various JIT types:

**PRE-JIT**: Compiles complete source code to native code in a single operation.

**ECONO-JIT**: Compiles only methods called at Runtime.

**NORMAL-JIT**: Compiles only methods called at Runtime and stored in cache.